# Rails - Validate field in another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Need some help on figuring out how to validate one field if and only if another field in a related model is of a certain value.  For example:

//My Models

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :course
end
```

A course can have many locations (state, city, etc) as well as a start_date.  I want to have something like: "Allow location.start_date to be blank ONLY IF course.format == 'DVD'"

In my Location model I tried something like:

```
validates_presence_of   :start_date,
                        :message => "Start Date can't be blank",
                        :allow_blank => false,
                        :if => Proc.new { |course| self.course.format != 'DVD' }
```

Then when I use that, I get:
private method 'format' called for nil:NilClass

Not sure if I'm on the right track here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `Proc` passed to the `if` clause passes as a parameter to the block the instance of the current object being validated. So, what you have as `|course|` is really `|location|`. Try something like the following and see if it does what you want:

```
validates_presence_of   :start_date,
                        :message => "Start Date can't be blank",
                        :allow_blank => false,
                        :if => Proc.new { |location| location.course.format != 'DVD' }
```

Comment: @Brandon...That makes sense.  I had it backwards.  The only problem now, as this maybe borderline for a different question, is that when creating a new course, I get private method 'format' called for nil:NilClass.  I believe this is because the course hasn't actually been created yet and the location has nothing to link to yet.

Comment: You could modify your proc to say `|location| !location.course.nil? && location.course.format != 'DVD'`